# Rewrite rules and base url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, relative-path

When one uses a rewrite rule, say:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.+?)/?$ index.php?type=foo&value=$1 [NC,L]
```

The client still sees this as a url `server.dom/foo/bar/` (it has no knowledge how these url's are resolved internally, which is of course reasonable).

If the page `index.php` however generate a link (`<a href="baz">link</a>`), the client will interpret this as `server.dom/foo/bar/baz`. `index.php` however has in many cases no full knowledge about where the url originates from...

A first idea was to pass the depth of the "virtual" path as a parameter. Thus the rewrite rule would be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.+?)/?$ index.php?type=foo&depth=2&value=$1 [NC,L]
```

As a result, `index.php` should write:

```
<base href="../../">
```

Or more formally `depth` times `..` (separated by slashes). In some cases, however, `.htaccess` has no knowledge about the depth of the "virtual" path as well. Furthermore one can note that the last slash (`/`) in the rewrite rule is optional, depending on whether the slash was written down, the depth varies. This would increase the number of `RewriteRules` significantly...

What are good/better practices to resolve this relative links problem robustly (robust perhaps in the sense that *moving* parts of the website will not "break" the links)?

Comment: Are you trying to emulate absolute paths by relative? And are you know about RewriteBase and <base /> tag?

Comment: I would make a C macro and create a PHP extension located in `/ext/YOUR_EXT_NAME`

Comment: @MichaelLivach: Well one does not know the "root" of the website, so absolute links are no option...

Answer (score 2):

If you're using pretty links I would strongly suggest not use relative links. You can use links as:

```
<a href="<?php base(); ?>baz">link</a>
```

where `base()` function is defined in some `config.php` to output `/foo/`.

That way link will resolve to `/foo/baz` instead of `/foo/bar/baz`. If you have to move your website to some other path just update your `base()` function inside your `config.php`. This is same as what many CMS frameworks do like Wordpress or CakePHP.

Comment: Probably a mis-placed quote at the start of the string "baz" in your example.